# stacking div on top of text relative to container div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a text reveal animation. for that I have 2 `div`s that need to be on top of `h1` & `h3` tags inside an `anim-container` parent div. The `.anim-container` is a flexbox with `column` flex-direction. And it looks like this:

[image: current layout]

Here's the html and SCSS:

```css
.anim-container {
  width: 500px;
  //height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.rectbg {
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}

.rectbg2 {
  @extend .rectbg;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-container">
  <h1 ref="title" class="title">title text!</h1>
  <h3 ref="subtitle" class="subtitle">this is subtitle text</h3>
  <div ref="rectbg" class="rectbg"></div>
  <div ref="rectbg2" class="rectbg2"></div>
</div>
```

I want the pink and yellow divs to stack on top of the 2 headings. So I can then animate them and create a text reveal animation. What is the best possible way of doing something like this? Also If I do `position: absolute` the divs shoot up to the top of page which isn't what i want I want them to be inside the border of `anim-container`

Comment: are you using the yellow and pink div only for text reveal animation or do they have other purpose also ?

Comment: only for reveal animation, I'll remove them from DOM after the animation is done playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also If I do position: absolute the divs shoot up to the top of page
>   which isn't what i want I want them to be inside the border of
>   anim-container

Then first set `anim-container`'s `position` property to `relative`. After that, make children `absolute`. It will not shoot up to the top of page.

```css
.anim-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position:relative;
}

.rectbg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.rectbg2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-container">
  <h1 ref="title" class="title">title text!</h1>
  <h3 ref="subtitle" class="subtitle">this is subtitle text</h3>
  <div ref="rectbg" class="rectbg"></div>
  <div ref="rectbg2" class="rectbg2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing text reveal animation without the yellow and pink div is by using css animations.

```css
.anim-container {
  width: 500px;
  //height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

h1, h3 {
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: text-reveal;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes text-reveal {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes text-reveal {
  from {color: white;}
  to {color: #222222;}
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-container">
  <h1 ref="title" class="title">title text!</h1>
  <h3 ref="subtitle" class="subtitle">this is subtitle text</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work. I need the divs because the animation I'm aiming for is much more complex than simply changing colors. I need a way to stack the divs on the heading tags.

Comment: Also, I'm using gsap with vue for this.